# Elixir - Phoenix - Ecto terminology

Tags: elixir

Is the `schema table_name do ... end` function and is it the `field :title, :string` also function? Or what is these whole thing being called?

```
use MyApp, :model // import Ecto module to use its chema

// is schema is a custom type or sth or function, how to call it?
schema "documents" do
  // and this line also
  field :title, :string

  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: They are both macros. Check out the docs (there is even a link to the source code if you want to take a closer look):
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#schema/2
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3

Comment: there are nothing says about they are macros thou from both your link

Comment: It is written `(macro)` on the right side, next to `</>`. But you may also look at the actual source code: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L354 https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.2.10/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L461

Comment: oh yes I can see that now